# Best place for adding autolayout constraints in code

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

What is the best place for adding autolayout constraints programmatically? For custom views and for controllers too. Some people does this in `init()` method, other people use `updateConstraints()` (with flag which guarantees that constraints are added only once). I watched all WWDC videos and read all sample code from Apple but I'm confused because I can't find answer. Everybody does it differently. So what is the best approach for adding constraints from code?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there's no best approach. You can apply constraints anywhere as long as view has been initialised. I usually apply constraints before `-willLayoutSubviews` is called, so my constraints will be considered in the initial layout cycle and I don't have to call layout explicitly. You can apply them as early as `-init` override if you want, and as late as you want. Just remember to call `-layoutIfNeeded` if you modify constraints at some point after the initial layout calls.

Answer (score 0):

There is NO best place to add autolayouts contraints in code. It all depends on what your implementation is, and what you want to achieve or do.

That is also the same reason why everybody is doing it differently.